# How to get the name of the group with maximum value of parameter?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a DataFrame `df` like this one:

df =

```
name  group   influence
A     1       2
B     1       3
C     1       0
A     2       5
D     2       1
```

For each distinct value of `group`, I want to extract the value of `name` that has the maximum value of `influence`.

The expected result is this one:

```
group  max_name   max_influence
1      B          3
2      A          5
```

I know how to get max value but I don't know how to get`max_name`.

```
df.groupBy("group").agg(max("influence").as("max_influence")
```

Answer (score -3):

There is good alternative to `groupBy` with structs - window functions, which sometimes are really faster.
For your examle I would try the following:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
val w = Window.partitionBy('group)
val res = df.withColumn("max_influence", max('influence).over(w))
  .filter('influence === 'max_influence)
res.show
+----+-----+---------+-------------+
|name|group|influence|max_influence|
+----+-----+---------+-------------+
|   A|    2|        5|            5|
|   B|    1|        3|            3|
+----+-----+---------+-------------+
```

Now all you need is to drop useless columns and rename remaining ones.
Hope, it'll help.